# Set baseURL from .env in VueAxios

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, axios

I am using a standard [Vue starer webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) with VueAxios installed. I want to configure axios using .env variable when building with `dev` command. I have everything set up within `/config/index.js`:

```
const devEnv = require('./dev.env')
module.exports = {
...
    host: devEnv.host || 'localhost',
    port: devEnv.port || 8080,
...
}
```

Then I define my host and port in `dev.env.js` in the same directory and it all works fine.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'})

let host = process.env.VUE_HOST;
let port = +process.env.VUE_PORT;

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
    NODE_ENV: '"development"',
    host,
    port
})
```

But the problem is that I can't access host value within `src/main.js` of my Vue app.

If I try to do it like this I get an error that

> vue is not defined

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
...
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = `http://${process.env.host}:${process.env.port}`;
```

Though the port works fine, the host does not and throws an error.

Comment: Have you imported `Vue`?

Comment: Yes, I just skipped that part for simplicity. It's a standard vue-cli webpack template.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE for Vue CLI 3**

All you need to do now is just set `VUE_APP_BASE_URL` in your `.env` file. Then you'll be able to access it like this:

```
process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
```

But an even better solution would be to [configure a dev server](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver).

---

**Previous solution**

Solution was quite simple:

- Define a special variable for that case within `webpack.dev.conf.js` plugins, omit using `process.env` for that.

  ```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': require('../config/dev.env'),  // You can't use this for baseURL
      'baseURL': JSON.stringify(`http://${HOST || config.dev.host}:${PORT || config.dev.port}`)
  }),
  ```
- In `\src\main.js` define it like this:

  ```
  if (typeof baseURL !== 'undefined')
  {
      Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above helped me. But I want to make an amendment. In `/src/main.js` need define constant.

Example:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
if (typeof baseURL !== 'undefined') {
  Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
}
```

Also don't need to add code in file `webpack.dev.conf.js`. Although maybe this is only suitable for my problem.

My problem: [Dynamic host in axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597306/dynamic-host-in-axios)

Answer (score 1):

Note that only **NODE_ENV, BASE_URL**, and variables that start with **VUE_APP_** will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin.

so variable name like **VUE_APP_HOST**

please refer link : https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables