# Dynamic host in axios

Tags: symfony, vue.js, axios, symfony4

How can I create a dynamic host in `axios`?

**Example:**

```
 const host = location.hostname;
 // axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://hastore.local';
 axios.defaults.baseURL = host;
 axios.defaults.port = 8080;
 axios.get('api/categories')
 .then((res) => {
      this.categories = res.data;
      console.log(res);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
      console.warn('error during http call', err);
 });
```

String `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://hastore.local';` does not fit, because on prodaction don't be work.

String `const host = location.hostname;` also not a solution, because I get incorrect port and dublicate host.

[image]

The goal is to get the right host depending on the environment.
I read a lot of articles about this, but I did not find a solution.
Thanks for help!

- axios version: e.g.: v0.16.2
- Environment: e.g.: node v8.9.4, chrome 64.0.3282.119, Ubuntu 16.04
- Symfony 4.0.4
- Vue.js 2.4.2
- vue-axios 2.0.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set baseURL from .env in VueAxios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205273/set-baseurl-from-env-in-vueaxios)

Answer (score 4):

You probably do not need to set baseURL. Have you tried to define baseURL each time you make requests? For example,

```html
axios.get(`${host}:${port}/api/categories`)
```

Or, depending on your words "The goal is to get the right host depending on the environment.", you may define proper host using your environment variables, for example:

```html
axios.get(`${proccess.env.HOST}:${PORT}/api/categories`)
```

If you use a bundler for your frontend code, this expression will be resolved to

```html
axios.get('http://example.com:80/api/categories')
```

That's because your bundler actually should run with pre-defined environment variables `HOST` and `PORT`

Comment: Yes, I need tried to define baseURL each time I make requests.

Comment: With environment variables good idea, but I'm not sure that I have access to them. @AchmedzianovDanilian

Comment: I get `undefined` when to printing in console `console.log(process.env.HOST);`

Comment: You have to define environment variables before call build, of course. And you'll get undefined if variables you call are not defined.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Add this code in your: `/src/main.js`

Example:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
if (typeof baseURL !== 'undefined') {
  Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
}
```

The answer that helped me in this: [Set baseURL from .env in VueAxios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205273/set-baseurl-from-env-in-vueaxios/48598009#48598009)

Thanks everyone for help!