# How to set POST request via axios on REST API?

Tags: javascript, symfony, vue.js, axios, api-platform.com

How to set POST request via axios on REST API?

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Kbh.png)

I see that get uncorrect headers, but I don't understand, why?
Also, I often come across the fact that the documentation of the axios simply doesn't work.

Example get GET request, it works:
[Dynamic host in axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597306/dynamic-host-in-axios/48598061#48598061)

```js
const configAxios = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
};
const data = JSON.stringify({
  cardData: this.cardData.brand,
});
axios.post('api/products', {
  data,
},
  configAxios,
)
.then((req) => {
  this.data = req.data;
  console.log(req);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.warn('error during http call', err);
});
```

This is necessary to get the host API:

p.s.: this will be work only in this way.

```js
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
if (typeof baseURL !== 'undefined') {
  Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
}
```

- axios version: e.g.: v0.16.2
- Environment: e.g.: node v8.9.4, chrome 64.0.3282.119, Ubuntu 16.04
- Symfony 4.0.4
- Vue.js 2.4.2
- vue-axios 2.0.2

Comment: Axios config is passed as the third parameter, not a field in the data object.

Comment: @NickTucci in any case I get `Unauthorized header content-type`

Comment: @NickTucci I fixed code.

Comment: Is it your server or axios returning that error?

Comment: @NickTucci, server, he waits for the necessary headlines, but axios don't want to give their, as I understand.

Comment: It's probably a CORS error, maybe do you need to use NelmioCors with API Platform if the client is on another domain than the server.

Comment: @KévinDunglas, thank you a lot, NelmioCors really helped. You can add an answer, I'll mark it as correct. And it would be great, if you raise a topic, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API and the client are on separate domain names, you need to properly configure CORS headers to allow the client contacting the server. You also need to whitelist the authorized headers.

With API Platform and Symfony, you can easily do it using [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle). If you use Symfony 4/Flex, run:

```
$ composer req cors
```

The package will be automatically installed and properly configured. `Content-Type] will even be [whitelisted](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/nelmio/cors-bundle/1.5/config/packages/nelmio_cors.yaml#L6).