# Unexpected URL generated while using window.location.hostname

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to append URL, but it the generated URL is not as expected. Below is the code that I've tested and its outcome.

Since I'm using a local server to test my system, the desired request URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts`. I will be deploying this system to a remote server in the near future so I cannot use the request URL as it is now. Base on the code below, what I am trying to do is to get the current hostname and append it with the route URL but it produces weird URL. How to solve this?

**Component**

```
created() {
        var test = window.location.hostname + '/api/posts';
        this.axios.get(test).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data.data;
    });
```

[image]

**Route Api (api.php)**

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index');
```

Comment: If you just prefix your URL's with a `forward slash`, axios is smart enough to know to use the hostname anyway.

Comment: so how to solve the problem?

Comment: but what if my current url is `foo/bar/`? This will create `http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/bar/api/posts`. How to make it `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts`?

Comment: No, it won't. If you DO NOT use a `/` then it will assume a `relative` path. If you DO use a `/`, then it will assume it's a root path.

Comment: I still dont understand the part `DO NOT use /`. So I just have to put `this.axios.get('apiposts')` without the `/`?

Comment: No. I'm talking about the difference between relative and absolute URL's. If you DO NOT use a `/`, then it is RELATIVE to the current URL. so if you were on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/bar` and you did `this.axios.get('apiposts')` then your URL would be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/bar/apiposts`. But if you did `this.axios.get('/apiposts')`, then it would be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiposts`. because of the `affixed

Comment: Holy moly now I understand...Can you post your answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an absolute URL in your axios requests if you don't want to have to configure a base URL:

```
this.$axios.get('/apiposts')
```

Where the prefixed `/` is the important part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to set baseURL. Have you tried to define baseURL? For example:

```
axios.get(`${process.env.HOST}:${PORT}/api/categories`)
```

Add this code in your: `/src/main.js`

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
if (typeof baseURL !== 'undefined') {
  Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
}
```

See the solution here [Set baseURL from .env in VueAxios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205273/set-baseurl-from-env-in-vueaxios/48598009#48598009)

I think in your app baseURL is set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` (default) and you append the host to this url in this line `var test = window.location.hostname + '/api/posts';`. Try it without this.